# $321$-avoiding in $S_5$.

Tags: combinatorics

It is said that the number of $321$-avoiding permutations in $S_n$ ($n \geq 3$) is the $n$-th Catalan number, see [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.2684v1.pdf) and the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern). I verified that the number of $321$-avoiding permutations is $14$. I think that the number of $321$-avoiding permutations in $S_5$ is $42$. But when I list the permutations I obtain $41$.

\begin{align}
&\left[1,2,3,4,5\right],\left[2,1,3,4,5\right],\left[1,3,2,4,5\right],\left[3,1,2,4,5\right],\left[2,3,1,4,5\right],\left[1,2,4,3,5\right],\left[2,1,4,3,5\right],\\
& \left[1,4,2,3,5\right],\left[4,1,2,3,5\right],\left[2,4,1,3,5\right],\left[1,3,4,2,5\right],\left[3,1,4,2,5\right],\left[3,4,1,2,5\right],\left[2,3,4,1,5\right],\\
&\left[1,2,3,5,4\right],\left[2,1,3,5,4\right],\left[1,3,2,5,4\right],\left[3,1,2,5,4\right],\left[2,3,1,5,4\right],\left[1,2,5,3,4\right],\left[2,1,5,3,4\right],\\
& \left[1,5,2,3,4\right],\left[5,1,2,3,4\right],\left[2,5,1,3,4\right],\left[1,3,5,2,4\right],\left[3,1,5,2,4\right],\left[3,5,1,2,4\right],\left[2,3,5,1,4\right],\\
& \left[1,2,4,5,3\right],\left[2,1,4,5,3\right],\left[1,4,2,5,3\right],\left[4,1,2,5,3\right],\left[2,4,1,5,3\right],\left[1,4,5,2,3\right],\left[4,1,5,2,3\right],\\
&\left[4,5,1,2,3\right],\left[2,4,5,1,3\right],\left[1,3,4,5,2\right],\left[3,1,4,5,2\right],\left[3,4,1,5,2\right],\left[3,4,5,1,2\right] 
\end{align}
Which $321$-avoiding permutation is not in the above list? Thank you very much.

Comment: The 321-avoiding permutation which is not in the list is 2,3,4,5,1.